# How can I copy a sheet to a new uncreated workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

This is a really dumb question but I don't find the answer in the book I have and at work I don't have internet. 
What I wanna do is to save a worksheet from the activeworkbook to a new file. I tried to do it this way but obviously you can't assign a worksheet directly to an uncreated workbook.

```
Public Sub SaveRaport() 
Dim ws As Worksheet 
Set ws = Worksheets("Raport") 
Dim wb As Workbook 
wb = ws 'here's the problem… I don't know how to do this thing 
Dim TempFilePath, TempFileName, FileExtStr, adrmail As String

wb.Save 
TempFilePath = "C:\Users\ionadr\Desktop\test" & "\" 
TempFileName = "Raportare" & " " & Format(data, "dd-mmm-yy ") & " schimbul " & schimb 
FileExtStr = "." & LCase(Right(wb.Name, Len(wb.Name) - InStrRev(wb.Name, ".", , 1))) 
    MsgBox ("Saving file...") 
    wb.SaveCopyAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr 
End Sub
```

I appreciate your help! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply looking to save the worksheet "Raport" and nothing else, something along these lines will get you started:

```
Sub Report()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Raport")

    ws.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "NewCopy.xlsx"

End Sub
```

Obviously you'll have to modify the filename to suit your needs.  If you don't want to save the new copy just yet, calling ws.Copy alone will create a new workbook with the data in the "Raport" spreadsheet (in my experience -- just tested the code a minute ago too).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

your `wb = ws` must be throwing errors. You are trying to set two objects equal to eachother that are different types (not possible).

```
Dim newWB As Workbook
Dim originalWorkbook As Workbook 'declare a variable of the workbook type (still an uncreated file)
Set newWB = Workbooks.Add() 'create your new file
Set originalWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
originalWorkbook.Sheets(2).Copy after:=newWB.Sheets(1) 'replace the sheet indicies I used with whatever yours are or with strings...
```

then you can save the workbook using the saveas method
`newWB.SaveAs()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that you need and that I use almost all the time. Assuming that you want to export a sheet called "Report" as C:\Report.xlsx

```
Sub ExportSummary()

Dim WsToExport As Worksheet
Set WsToExport = Sheets("Report")
Dim CurrentWbk As Workbook
Dim NewWbk As Workbook

Set CurrentWbk = ActiveWorkbook

Workbooks.Add
Set NewWbk = ActiveWorkbook

CurrentWbk.Activate
WsToExport.Select
WsToExport.Copy Before:=NewWbk.Sheets(1)

NewWbk.Activate
NewWbk.SaveAs "C:\Report.xlsx"
NewWbk.Close

End Sub
```